# How to create a pickerview in ios swift with multiple selection

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios7

I have tried ALPICKERVIEW but it was in objective C
Please tell me any way to get this

How to create a picker view in ios swift with multiple selection??

I know i can achieve this by multiple selection in uitableview but i need it HOW??? Please tell me.

Comment: you can use ALPICKERVIEW of objective - c in swift too.

Answer (score 0):

You can import ObjectiveC in Swift through Bridging the code in swift.

- Add .m (implemetation) files of ObjC in your project
- Xcode will ask to create a bridging header like below[image]
- Click Yes

  You can find more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Find the Answer form this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Also watch in this [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pvys-KlC2V4) video about bridging ObjectiveC in Swift.